# How to get the response body in utf8 format in firefox add-on using request

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I user request in firefox add-on and I got headers details but I don't know how to get response body can any one help me out. I got full text using response.text but I need it in utf8 format for example(in node we use encoding(utf8)). I tried json.parse, but it returns null, though I get response.text
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request

Comment: I got body by response.text, but what I really want is in utf8 format.  And when I do json.parse I get nothing(null). That is what I really mean in question, but I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all the response object properties on [this part of the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request#response). I use `response.json` as it's already a JavaScript object (effectively the same as `JSON.parse(response.text);`)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is on that page. Once you have the response object, use

```
response.text
```

to get the plain text response.